# Python 3 - print traceback and stop execution on worker exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

In my application, I'm using several worker threads and a mainloop which is a part of external module and can't be modified. When a worker thread raises an exception, the app should stop the mainloop, do some cleanup, print the worker exception traceback and exit. The mainloop should be stopped by raising ExitMainLoop exception.

Here's an example code:

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread


class MyException(BaseException):
    pass


class ExitMainLoop(BaseException):
    pass


def main_loop():
    # this is a part of external module
    print('started main loop')
    try:
        while True:
            print('.')
            sleep(1)
    except ExitMainLoop:
        pass


def do_work():
    print('started worker thread')
    sleep(5)
    raise MyException


def main():
    worker = Thread(target=do_work)
    worker.daemon = True
    worker.start()
    main_loop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

EDIT: my real problem is that my application is using urwid library for curses ui so i can't see worker exceptions.

Comment: Exceptions don't cross thread boundaries like that. You say mainloop is 3rd party code that you can't modify? Does it have a defined mechanism to terminate the loop? If not, your thread may be able to do something like `os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)`. But it ain't going to be graceful unless the mainloop program has a wayto make it so.

Comment: The proper way to stop the mainloop is to raise ExitMainLoop exception

Answer (score 0):

I have a weird idea, might work maybe.

```
   def kill(ex_cls, ex, tb):
       os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)

    sys.excepthook = kill
```

When any exception occurs get the process id and kill it.